# Book about people cut off from rest of the world that don't kill animals

Tags: identification-request

I read this book in elementary school (less than 10 years old) so I think it was a young adult or children's book. It's about inhabitants of a valley that were cut off from the outside world. The main characters were kids in school. It was like an agrarian society of some sort, like a small village or maybe a series of small villages. I think people from outside are coming into the valley and the characters inside are worried about it upsetting their peaceful society (but it's not dystopian, their society really is peaceful).

The most clear distinguishing detail I can remember is that the main characters find a bag with a map or something like that in it, and they are shocked when they find out the bag is made out of a mysterious material that turns out to be leather (they don't kill animals so they have no leather).

The kids try to find the exit to the valley I think. There may be like a cliff or canyon involved at some point.

The characters might have been animals, like rabbits maybe, but I can't remember for sure. It was all text, not a picture book.

This book was written in English.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature SE. Could you please add what language you read this book in?